# Thread get killed without exception

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool

I get `cItems` which is a `IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>` provided by Selenium.
However. I make the function Single Thread based, it works nice. But now I wanted to increase performance and so I choosed the **.Net ThreadPool**.

```
ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(16, 16);

IEnumerator<IWebElement> iter = cItems.GetEnumerator();
while(iter.MoveNext()) {
  cThreadJobObj.Item = iter.Current;
  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(GetThreadJob), cThreadJobObj.Clone()); // .Clone() is a deep clone
}
```

The Problem now is, that the Threads disappear, in Line 5. There isn't any Exception thrown, I think because the `} catch (Exception Ex) {` block isn't called.

```
public static void GetThreadJob(object ThreadJob) {
  try {
    var cThreadJob = ThreadJob as ThreadJobObj;
    var IWebElement = cThreadJob.Item;
    var cElem = cItem.FindElement(By.CssSelector("span.im_message_date_text"));
  } catch (Exception Ex) {
    Rupert.Logger.E("{Thread.GetCurrentProcessorId()} on Obj {cThreadJob.iCount}", Ex, false);
  }
}
```

The  `GetThreadJob` is called by all 16 Threads, and all disappear at the same line.

[image]

#### Update

I separated the line and the Threads disappear in this method [`ISearchContext.FindElement Method`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/).

```
IWebElement.FindElement(By)
```

If I make a quickwatch on this line, this is the value:

```
cItem.FindElement(cSel) Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation. OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement
```

Comment: If you run it in a debugger with "Break on thrown" (debug menu.. exceptions.. tick next to CLR) set, does it break?

Comment: @CaiusJard Now, I ticked every single. They are all disappearing on the same line.

Comment: But what is the line? Is any exception being thrown at all?

Comment: @CaiusJard nothing is thrown. `var cElem = cItem.FindElement(By.CssSelector("span.im_message_date_text"));` in here the thread disappear. I can see that because I make a `Console.WriteLine` before and after. Further, during debugging, the process switches to the next waiting thread. If all passed this line, the program is waiting for I/O because the callback, which is in the bottom getting reached.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after a long night I found out, that the **.Net** Limits the Sockets which could be opened, during the Selenium Process.

The default value for `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` is 2 and 10 for `Asp.net`. [More Info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit?view=net-5.0#property-value)

This can be avoided through this in the init of the script:

```
         ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(Environment.ProcessorCount / 2, 25);
         ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(Environment.ProcessorCount * 4, 100);

         ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm = true;
         ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
         ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 65000;
         ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime = 500;
```